# How can i solve the problem of missing constraints in constraint layout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

The view is not constrained. It only has design time positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime
The attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor.

Comment: Have you added the constraints? If you have then please be more specific about the problem and images to display the anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your view both vertical and horizontal constraints so in the run time he will have its position relative to the screen. If you won't do it your view will have no vertical/horizontal place to be and will jump from its location to the start if the screen.

You can do it like this for example:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Also, you can check the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) for more information.